# Power BI - Melhor prática importação de grande quantidade de dados

Tags: data, microsoft, powerbi

Sou novo no ramo de BI, e tenho que fazer o BI de pouco mais de 25 milhões de registros.

A importação para o Power BI é inviável, já que o arquivo ficaria com mais de 1gb e seria impossível de postá-lo na web. Por isso optei pelo DirectQuery.
Só que o carregamento dos dashboards na web estão muito lentos.

Gostaria de saber qual é a melhor prática para a importação de grandes quantidades de dados no Power Bi. Se é com DirectQuery (mesmo demorando bastante para carregar os dashboards e muitas vezes nem carregando por causa do TimeOut),  com Analysis Service ou outro tipo de importação.

Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se você conhece um pouco da linguagem SqL daria para sumarizar boa parte das informações.Se não for possível sumarizar, importe apenas as colunas que você vai realmente utilizar no painel. e trabalhe apenas com medidas, elas são mais rápidas.

Verifique também como estão as estruturas dos dados que você está usando. Pode ser que seja possível criar um index no banco para acelerar as consultas.

Outra coisa importante, o erro realmente está acontecendo por timeout? Ja tentou subir um painel com apenas 10 linhas? Já aconteceu comigo uma situação onde meu getway não estava funcionando corretamente.